# ASP.NET Excel export encoding problem

Tags: asp.net, encoding, character-encoding

I'm doing some Excel Exports on the ASP.NET Site.
Everything works except of the Encoding. When I open it in Excel, it looks like this:

> Eingabe Kosten je GerÃ¤t GerÃ¤t:
>   GerÃ¤tebezeichnung:
>   Betriebsmittel     HeizÃ¶l in â‚¬:    4
>   Dieselverbrauch in â‚¬:   4

This is my code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=NachkalkGeraete.xls;");
var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(Response.Output);

SomeControl.RenderControl(writer); /* FormView, Table, DataGrid... */

Response.End();
```

I've already tried explicitly set the Encoding.. but no change occured:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=NachkalkGeraete.xls");

Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
EnableViewState = false;

System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

SomeControl.RenderControl(hw);

Response.Write(tw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

What is wrong, please?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Well I found out that the problem could be in the header of the excel file, that it does not contain the **BOM byte sequence** (at the beginning of the file representing the encoding used).

So I made it this way and it works for me:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=Test.xls");   
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

FormView1.RenderControl(hw);

Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: As a minimalist I tried eliminating lines 4 (`ContentEncoding`) & 5 (`BinaryWrite`) and was surprised to find it didn't work. Excellent job on finding this solution. Respect! :)

Comment: I spent a few hours trying to get this to work and finally gave up and concatenated " " in front of my strings. A total hack. Thanks so much for figuring this out.

Comment: My last comment doesn't sound right. I was trying to figure out a solution on my own and wasn't able to get it fixed until I came across your answer. :-)

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried setting the encoding in a meta tag in the HTML?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Excel won't see the response headers, so it won't know what the `Response.Encoding` is. The meta tag allows it to find out.

Comment: I'm exporting a Control that is rendered which means that the file exported is html with a table only. no body, no headers. nothing..

Comment: Adding at least <html><head><meta... /></head><body>...</body> is probably worth while then.

Comment: Yeah but i think that's the same solution as to add a byte header with encoding.. anyways it's a file to be opened in office.. what do you think ?

Comment: YOU SAVE MY JOB! THANKS, THIS WORK PERFECTLY WITH WebApi (Asp.net WebApi return a IHttpAction result). Very thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 11):

For instances where UTF8 is needed...

```
FileInfo dataExportFile = new FileInfo(dsExport.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DataExportFile"].ToString());

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";                        
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dataExportFile.Name);
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
Response.TransmitFile(dataExportFile.FullName);
```

Answer (score 4):

I got same problem with spanish characters and solved it with this line of code.

```
        response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default ;
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

add
`Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());`

Comment: You should add a bit more than just code, such as where to add your one liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use "Server.HtmlDecode" to decode these words like "João"

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e){
String wrong = "Jo&#227;o";
String corrected = Server.HtmlDecode(wrong);}
```