# Currency export to Excel results in Â character for empty space

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am essentially exporting a webpage to Excel format. The export works fine, but when exporting Currency values that were formatted ToString("C") results in displaying the Â character in the Excel cell before any space in the money value.
For Example:
decimal Invoice = 322800.38;
decimal Allocated = 695.55;

Label1.Text = Invoice.ToString("C");
Label2.Text = Allocated.ToString("C");

After the export the value in excel is: R 322Â 827,27 (Wrong)
and R 695,55 (Correct)

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: System.IO.File.WriteAllText("path", "content", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679656/asp-net-excel-export-encoding-problem 
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually caused by a mis-interpretation of the encoding used to save it, when you have a hard space (160), usually given as `&nbsp;` in a web page. It looks like the web page is encoded as UTF8, but you're loading it into windows 'ANSI' format.

It depends on precisely what you're doing and how you're exporting, but you need to either change the encoding of the web page, or have excel use the encoding it was exported to when you import it.

Comment: Can you give an example - how to specify encoding while excel export - that would make this answer more complete

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679656/asp-net-excel-export-encoding-problem 
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());