# TableRow styling for Export To Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have following code that I am using for export to excel of a gridview. I am adding the gridview rows into System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table. Now, I need to apply background color to the header and data rows in the exported excel (There are two header rows).

I tired the following. It is not providing the desired result.

Issues of current solution

1. One header row does not have background color
2. Coloring is applied to cells that does not have data (cells “H”, “I”, etc.)

How can we correct it?

[image]

Note: I am trying to learn the export feature. So, please don't suggest to use any third party controls. I am just exploring all features of this approach.

I am adding the header grouping to the original gridview using following code.

```
protected void gvCustomers_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sbNewHeader = new StringBuilder();
        sbNewHeader.AppendFormat("&nbsp;</th>" +
            "<th colspan='2' class='tableColGroupAssociate'>Associate Info <a href='#' class='associateHide'> Hide </a> </th>" +
            "<th colspan='2' class='tableColGroupTransaction'>Financial Info <a href='#' class='financialHide'> Hide </a> </th>" +
            "<th colspan='2' class='tableColGroupDailyTax'>Tax Info <a href='#' class='dailyTaxHide'> Hide </a> </th>"
            + "</tr>");
        sbNewHeader.AppendFormat("<tr class='{0}'><th>{1}", this.gvCustomers.HeaderStyle.CssClass, e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = sbNewHeader.ToString();
    }
}
```

Complete Code

```
public static void Export(GridView gv)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "MyExcelFile.xls"));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter tetxWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table tableControl = new Table();
            tableControl.GridLines = gv.GridLines;

            //Before the next step - we can remove any controls inside the gridview and replace with literal control

            //  Add the header row to the table
            if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
            {
                TableRow tableRow = gv.HeaderRow;
                tableRow.Style[System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor] = "Orange";
                tableControl.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
            }

            //  Add each of the data rows to the table
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
            {
                TableRow tableRow = row;
                tableRow.Style[System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor] = "Yellow";
                tableControl.Rows.Add(row);
            }


            //  Render the table into the htmlwriter
            tableControl.RenderControl(tetxWriter);

            //  Render the htmlwriter into the response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();


        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on comment from Ankit, I tried the following; still the result is not as expected.

```
            if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
            {
                TableRow tableRow = gv.HeaderRow;

                foreach (TableCell cell in tableRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.Style[System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor] = "Orange";
                }
                tableControl.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
            }
```

[image]

---

Comment: What i am getting is you are copying entire row of gridView and pasting it in a Excel Row. I have a workaround for your problem but this is not recommended as you will be using unnecessary nested loop just for the sake of formatting, if you find it okay then you can use one more loop for columns inside the loop for rows then you will be adding value to each cell instead of one Row at a time, then the cells outside the gridView area will not get colors.

Comment: @Ankit Thanks. I tried your suggestion. Still there are issues as shown in the updated question. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could You, please debug the process step by step to understand what is actually happening there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a way to do it... For the benefit of others I will post it here:

References:

1. [ASP.NET Excel export encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679656/asp-net-excel-export-encoding-problem)

[image]

Other Note: When a new Table is created TableSection can be used to define header

```
 newRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

**CODE**

//Changed the logic used  for adding dynamic header for HTML rendering:

```
protected void gvCustomers_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridViewRow newHeaderRow = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

        TableCell cell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
        cell1.ColumnSpan = 1; //e.Row.Cells.Count;
        cell1.Text = "";

        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        cell2.ColumnSpan = 2;
        cell2.Text = "One";

        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
        cell3.ColumnSpan = 2;
        cell3.Text = "Two";

        TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
        cell4.ColumnSpan = 2;
        cell4.Text = "Three";

        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell1);
        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell2);
        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell3);
        newHeaderRow.Cells.Add(cell4);

        ((GridView)sender).Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, newHeaderRow);
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {

        //System.Text.StringBuilder sbNewHeader = new StringBuilder();
        //sbNewHeader.AppendFormat("&nbsp;</th>" +
        //    "<th colspan='2' class='tableColGroupAssociate'>Associate Info <a href='#' class='associateHide'> Hide </a> </th>" +
        //    "<th colspan='2' class='tableColGroupTransaction'>Financial Info <a href='#' class='financialHide'> Hide </a> </th>" +
        //    "<th colspan='2' class='tableColGroupDailyTax'>Tax Info <a href='#' class='dailyTaxHide'> Hide </a> </th>"
        //    + "</tr>");
        //sbNewHeader.AppendFormat("<tr class='{0}'><th>{1}", this.gvCustomers.HeaderStyle.CssClass, e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
        //e.Row.Cells[0].Text = sbNewHeader.ToString();


    }

}
```

//Export Logic - Applied similar logic once again

```
public static void Export(GridView gv)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "MyExcelFile.xls"));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";


    //Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    //Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());


    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter tetxWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table tableControl = new Table();
            tableControl.GridLines = gv.GridLines;

            //  Add the header row to the table
            if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
            {
                ReplaceControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);


                #region Dynamic Frrst Header Row

                TableRow newRow = new TableRow();

                TableCell cell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
                cell1.ColumnSpan = 1; 
                cell1.Text = "";

                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                cell2.ColumnSpan = 2;
                cell2.Text = "One";

                TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                cell3.ColumnSpan = 2;
                cell3.Text = "Two";

                TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
                cell4.ColumnSpan = 2;
                cell4.Text = "Three";

                newRow.Cells.Add(cell1);
                newRow.Cells.Add(cell2);
                newRow.Cells.Add(cell3);
                newRow.Cells.Add(cell4);

                foreach (TableCell cell in newRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.Style[System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor] = "Purple";
                }
                tableControl.Rows.Add(newRow);

                #endregion 

                TableRow originalHeaderRow = gv.HeaderRow;
                foreach (TableCell cell in originalHeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.Style[System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor] = "Orange";
                }
                tableControl.Rows.Add(originalHeaderRow);
            }


            //  Add each of the data rows to the table
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
            {
                ReplaceControlForExport(row);

                TableRow tableRow = row;
                foreach (TableCell cell in tableRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.Style[System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor] = "Yellow";
                }
                tableControl.Rows.Add(row);
            }


            //  Render the table into the htmlwriter
            tableControl.RenderControl(tetxWriter);

            //  Render the htmlwriter into the response
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();


        }
    }
  }

 private static void ReplaceControlForExport(Control mainControlElement)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < mainControlElement.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        Control currentControl = mainControlElement.Controls[i];

        if (currentControl is LinkButton)
        {
            mainControlElement.Controls.Remove(currentControl);
            mainControlElement.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((currentControl as LinkButton).Text));
        }
        else if (currentControl is ImageButton)
        {
            mainControlElement.Controls.Remove(currentControl);
            mainControlElement.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((currentControl as ImageButton).AlternateText));
        }
        else if (currentControl is HyperLink)
        {
            mainControlElement.Controls.Remove(currentControl);
            mainControlElement.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((currentControl as HyperLink).Text));
        }
        else if (currentControl is DropDownList)
        {
            mainControlElement.Controls.Remove(currentControl);
            mainControlElement.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((currentControl as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
        }
        else if (currentControl is CheckBox)
        {
            mainControlElement.Controls.Remove(currentControl);
            mainControlElement.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((currentControl as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
        }

        //Recursive Call
        if (currentControl.HasControls())
        {
            ReplaceControlForExport(currentControl);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over how your excel files are written take a look at [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Adding a table is as simple as

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
wb.Worksheets.Add(myDataTable);
wb.SaveAs("MySheet.xlsx");
```

Using the API you can code like this:

```
var rngTable = ws.Range("B2:F6");
rngTable.FirstCell().Style
    .Font.SetBold()
    .Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.CornflowerBlue)
    .Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center);
```

Comment: Writing out html, and letting excel figure out how to display it will never give you full control over the output. I always prefer this to the `RenderControl` approach.