# ASP.NET C# Styling a Caption / Header when exporting to excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to style my asp.net excel export a bit better, but I have no idea how to.

I have the following code

```
string filename = Constants.Fullname +"_CommissionSheet_"+DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")+".xls";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename);
    Response.Charset = "";
    // If you want the option to open the Excel file without saving than
    // comment out the line below
    // Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
    new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    //Styling the gridView header for Excel.
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#95c556");
    GridView2.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF9900");
    GridView3.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#db7464");

    int j = 1;
    //Set alternate row color
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        gvrow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        if (j <= GridView1.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (j % 2 != 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                {
                    gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
                }
            }
        }
        j++;
    }

    int jk= 1;
    //Set alternate row color
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        gvrow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        if (jk <= GridView2.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (jk % 2 != 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                {
                    gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
                }
            }
        }
        jk++;
    }

    int jkj = 1;
    //Set alternate row color
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView3.Rows)
    {
        gvrow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        if (jkj <= GridView3.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (jkj % 2 != 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                {
                    gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");
                }
            }
        }
        jk++;
    }

    //Add Header
    GridView1.Caption = "Paid:";
    GridView1.CaptionAlign = TableCaptionAlign.Left;

    GridView2.Caption = "Expected:";
    GridView2.CaptionAlign = TableCaptionAlign.Left;

    GridView3.Caption = "Unpaid:";
    GridView3.CaptionAlign = TableCaptionAlign.Left;


    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    GridView2.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    GridView3.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
    }
```

Which is working great at the moment. It Generates the following:
[image]

What I would like to do is add some size to the header and maybe make it bold too. So it would look like this:

[image]

At the moment, I have absolutely no idea how to achieve this, so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check this question out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525877/tablerow-styling-for-export-to-excel

Comment: @Niklas, I Did not spot that one, i'll check it out. Thank you.