# Export data to Excel file with ASP.NET MVC 4 C# is rendering into view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I am having trouble exporting data to Excel. The following seems to render the gridview into my View, instead of prompting the user to open with Excel, which I have installed on my machine.

```
 Public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{            
    var products = this.Repository.Products.ToList();

    var grid = new GridView();
    grid.DataSource = from p in products
                      select new
                      {
                          Id = p.Id,
                          Name = p.Name
                      };
    grid.DataBind();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    grid.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return View("MyView"); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It was something in the application that wasn't working when I was attempting to return the view. I ended having to use return RedirectToAction("Action", "MyController");

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I have tried your code and it works just fine.
The file is being created without any problem, this is the code I used (it's your code, I just changed the datasource for testing):

```
    public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
        var products = new System.Data.DataTable("teste");
        products.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(int));
        products.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(string));

        products.Rows.Add(1, "product 1");
        products.Rows.Add(2, "product 2");
        products.Rows.Add(3, "product 3");
        products.Rows.Add(4, "product 4");
        products.Rows.Add(5, "product 5");
        products.Rows.Add(6, "product 6");
        products.Rows.Add(7, "product 7");


        var grid = new GridView();
        grid.DataSource = products;
        grid.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        grid.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return View("MyView");
    }
```

Comment: Hmm. You're right. It must be something else in my application that is causing this. Thanks. I spent longer than I should have on this!

Comment: Why not use a `FileResult` action?

Comment: A good example, though cleaner to use the return Content method and only setting the header for filename.

Example:
`Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcelFile.xls");
return Content(sw.ToString(), "application/ms-excel");`

With this, you can get rid of all the other Response. statements in the example above. Additionally you won't have to return a view that is never really used.

Comment: For content encoding issues (that may burn you) see - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1685900/1560273

Comment: Guys,
Thanks for your response, how to export in multiple workbook any idea.

Comment: Does this have to be returned as a view or can I return the Excel file?

Comment: It generate an xml file not a standard excel file!

Answer (score 10):

You can call helper class in any controller

```
//view 
 @Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel", "Excel")

//controller Action
public void Excel()
{
    var model = db.GetModel()

    Export export = new Export();
    export.ToExcel(Response, model);
}

//helper class
public class Export
{        public void ToExcel(HttpResponseBase Response, object clientsList)
    {
        var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
        grid.DataSource = clientsList;
        grid.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        grid.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Step 1**: View page code

```
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value="Export" class="btn btn-primary" />
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#btnExport').click(function () {          

  window.location = '/Inventory/ExportInventory';

        });
});
</script>
```

**Step 2**:  Controller Code

```
  public ActionResult ExportInventory()
        {
            //Load Data
            var dataInventory = _inventoryService.InventoryListByPharmacyId(pId);
            string xml=String.Empty;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(dataInventory.GetType());

            using (MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlStream, dataInventory);
                xmlStream.Position = 0;
                xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream);
                xml = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
            }

            var fName = string.Format("Inventory-{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));

            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

            return File(fileContents, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fName);
        }
```

Comment: Result is not a correct excel file format. I used the exact code :(

Comment: add .xls extention

Answer (score 5):

```
  using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
  {
    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(mem, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

    // Add a row to the cell table.
    Row row;
    row = new Row() { RowIndex = 1 };
    sheetData.Append(row);

    // In the new row, find the column location to insert a cell in A1.  
    Cell refCell = null;
    foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
    {
      if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, "A1", true) > 0)
      {
        refCell = cell;
        break;
      }
    }

    // Add the cell to the cell table at A1.
    Cell newCell = new Cell() { CellReference = "A1" };
    row.InsertBefore(newCell, refCell);

    // Set the cell value to be a numeric value of 100.
    newCell.CellValue = new CellValue("100");
    newCell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
    {
      Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
      SheetId = 1,
      Name = "mySheet"
    };

    sheets.Append(sheet);

    workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
    spreadsheetDocument.Close();

    return File(mem.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "text.xlsx");
  }
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: I think they're using DocumentFormat.OpenXml which is a Microsoft created Open Office extension. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml?view=openxml-2.8.1)

Answer (score 4):

I have done this before, I think you need to remove the ActionResult. Make it a void and remove the return View(MyView). this is the solution

Answer (score 3):

I used a list in my controller class to set data into grid view. The code works fine for me:

```
public ActionResult ExpExcl()
{
  List<PersonModel> person= new List<PersonModel>
   { 
    new PersonModel() {FirstName= "Jenny", LastName="Mathew", Age= 23},
    new PersonModel() {FirstName= "Paul", LastName="Meehan", Age=25}
   };
   var grid= new GridView();
   grid.DataSource= person;
   grid.DataBind();

   Response.ClearContent();
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachement; filename=data.xls");
   Response.ContentType="application/excel";
   StringWriter sw= new StringWriter();
   HtmlTextWriter htw= new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 
   grid.RenderControl(htw);
   Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
   Response.Flush();
   Response.End();
   return View();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The modest way to export excel in MVC is using Microsoft CloseXml. I wrote a simple function for exporting my query result as excel sheet:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
...
public ActionResult ToExcel(List<Dictionary<string, string>> data, Dictionary<string, string> columnMap, string fileName, string sheetName)
{
    var dtDataBuffer = new System.Data.DataTable("buffer");

    foreach (string col in columnMap.Values)
    {
        dtDataBuffer.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));
    }



    foreach (var row in data)
    {
        List<string> rowData = new List<string> { };


        foreach (string col in columnMap.Keys)
        {
            rowData.Add(row[col]);
        }

        dtDataBuffer.Rows.Add(rowData.ToArray());
    }




    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(dtDataBuffer, sheetName);
        worksheet.Rows().Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        worksheet.Rows().Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
        worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
        workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
    }

    return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
}
```

And this is a usage example (in practice I use my own class to run query and generate data. You can find it here for [Oracle](https://gist.github.com/kingofnull/da17e4679a63d359ab9d3a3f01378701) and [SQL Server](https://gist.github.com/kingofnull/9963bfebedf6937522a95b3d2c515246)):

```
public ActionResult myReportExport(){
    var data=List<Dictionary<string, string>>(){
        {{"Column1_Index","Column1_Value"},{"Column2_Index","Column2_Value"},...}
        ...
    };
    
    
    return ToExcel(data, new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "Column1_Index", "Column1 Title" } ,
            { "Column2_Index", "Column2 Title" } ,
            ...
        },
        "myFileName.xlsx",
        "my sheet name"
    );
}
```