# Post html table to controller from view in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The whole meaning of this is that I'm trying to take a table from my view and create an Excelsheet from it with EPPlus. I have a table in my view where I us html helpers to display values from my model. When the table is fully created I wanna send it to my controller when clicking on a button. When the table is in my controller I need to access the table values so I from there can create my Excelsheet.

The big problem I have right now is that I can't successfully send my html table to my controller. And when I have it in my controller, how do I access the values? If possible (I guess not) it would be great to send the table as a DataTable to the controller. So far I have tried using ajax but I if there is any other way I can work with that as well

My view:

```
@model IEnumerable<CalcFactory.Models.Calculation>
<table cellspacing="0" width="80%" id"detailTable">
@{var rowID = 0;}
@{var cellID = 1;}
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr id="@rowID">
        <td align="center">
            @rowID
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="A-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PeriodStartDate)
            - @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.PeriodEndDate)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="B-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceAmount)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="C-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestRate)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="D-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestAmount)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="E-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amortization)
        </td>
        <td align="center" id="F-@cellID">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresentValue)
        </td>
    </tr>
    rowID++;
    cellID++;
}
</table>
```

My controller:

```
public class SaveController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SaveExcel(DateTable dt)
    {
        //Work with table values here. How?
    }
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveIcon', function () {
    var data = $('#detailTable').html();
    var url = "/Save/SaveExcel";
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: url,
       data: data,
       datatype: DataTable
   )}
});
```

My model:

```
public partial class Calculation
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime PeriodStartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime PeriodEndDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:.00}")]
    public decimal InvoiceAmount { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P6}")]
    public decimal InterestRate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:.00}")]
    public decimal InterestAmount { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:.00}")]
    public decimal Amortization { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:.00}")]
    public decimal PresentValue { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:.00}")]
    public decimal StartValue { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfDays { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You would need to pass your model to your controller method, not a datatable. Also, you would need to serialize the form first, not post the form's html

Comment: You can't use a type of `DataTable` with jQuery, most people would submit the table using form-encoding, or as JSON. Then from the server, you could bind/deserialze the JSON to a model or something like that.

Comment: You have code-help for me? I'm kind a new to this..

Comment: @mituw16 I don't really know what you mean. How can I send my whole model from view to controller?

Comment: I suggest you research MVC with .net and go from there. This is a pretty basic question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send your model data to the view, and then back to your controller. You instead need to send your model data directly to Excel. You might think of Excel as the view.

There are many resources related to this. Here's one I found by searching for "mvc export to excel c#"

[Export data to Excel file with ASP.NET MVC 4 C# is rendering into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346227/export-data-to-excel-file-with-asp-net-mvc-4-c-sharp-is-rendering-into-view)

Useing the example from the thread above, there's a method - public ActionResult ExportToExcel()

You can create a button (a link really), that will call this method. So the link would be, for instance...

```
<a href="yourcontrollername/ExportToExcel">export to excel</a>
```

EDIT - I just noticed your ajax call... That's where you would call the method, so...

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveIcon', function () {
```

would be

```
$('#mylinkid').click(function () {
```

Comment: But I only want to create it when clicked on button? so it's the users choice

Comment: right - the button would call the routine that creates the excel. I'll add some detail to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing for you to do would be to rerun the query when you click the button. Is there some sort of identifier you can use to run the same query?

My suggestion would be to pass some sort of id to an action method in your controller. Then you rerun the query to get the same data (or more up to date data). You can use that to populate your spreadsheet.

You CAN post the entire model from the view to the controller if you absolutely have to, but that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: The model is used to create annuity calculations and they can all be different from eachother. In my head (doesn't mean it's right) I need to get the first or entire model (because the second one is depending on the first, and so on)

Comment: Cant you rerun the calculation in the controller though? Whatever method you used to produce the table in the view should work to produce the data for the spreadsheet, shouldn't it? You would never want to pass the html from the table up to the controller. At most you would want to pass the model up to the controller, but in this case i dont think thats necessary either. Also you generally wouldn't want a "SaveController". Maybe something more like an AnnuityController? It should be in a similar folder structure to your View.

Comment: I've got an AnnuityController for the calculation. I will try your approach it seems to work (once again, in my head)