# How to increase size of rows in Datatable vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, web-applications, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

I use DataTable for export data to excel, but the final file doesn't show well data sized more than 10 caracters.

[image]

for example the value 1,65987E+11 is recorded in database and in code  "165987000501" as string 
So is there any solution for inscrease the cell size for show more numbers ? 
Regards.

Comment: Enclose the value in quotes, so Excel knows to treat it as a string and not a number.

Comment: Another option would be changing cell format to Number with 0 decimals.

Comment: how do you export to excel ?

Comment: this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346227/export-data-to-excel-file-with-asp-net-mvc-4-c-sharp-is-rendering-into-view @patel

Comment: and which option could use for set length , i tried many ways without result

Comment: this link ... is not a good answer