# Arabic Characters are not recognized when exporting gridview to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, arabic

I have problem with recognizing the Arabic Characters when I export gridviews to Excel. The Arabic text appears like "Ø®Ù„Ø§Øµ" , it doesn't recognize the Arabic data as well as the Arabic gridview header

I'm using the following code for exporting to Excel many gridviews in the same web application, it works ok and it recognize the Arabic text

```C#
protected void BtnExportDateSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportDataDateSearch.xls");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    StringWriter StringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter HtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(StringWriter);
    GridView1.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter);

    Response.Write(StringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

The difference between the cases that I have, in case I retrieve the data into gridview from the usual select query, it recognize the Arabic text 
but in case I use unpivot and CASE statement, the Arabic is viewed ok on the gridview in the asp page but when I export it to excel, the Arabic text is not recognized.

This is the stored procedure which is the datasource of my gridview:

```SQL
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UnpivotApprovedPalms]
    @StartDateTime datetime2(7),
    @EndDateTime datetime2(7)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        FarmID, 
        CASE PalmsName 
            WHEN 'kalas' THEN N'خلاص'
            WHEN 'khnizi' THEN N'خنيزي'
            WHEN 'jashKharma' THEN N'جش خرمة'
            WHEN 'anbaratAlMadina' THEN N'عنبرة المدينة'
            WHEN 'NabtatSaif' THEN N'نبتة سيف'
            ELSE PalmsName 
        END AS 'PalmsName',
        Quantity, TransactionDateTime
    FROM 
        [ApprovedPalmsInFarm] 
    UNPIVOT
        (Quantity
         FOR PalmsName IN ([kalas], [khnizi], [jashKharma], [anbaratAlMadina])
        ) u   
    WHERE
        u.TransactionDateTime >= @StartDateTime 
        AND u.TransactionDateTime <= @EndDateTime;

    RETURN
END
```

What is wrong in the codes which cause this problem? whey when I change the query it works ok, but especially with my unpivot query with case statement the Arabic not recognized? the asp page can view the gridview with Arabic text correctly, but only when I export it to Excel the Arabic is not recognized

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the header of the excel file

```
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportDataDateSearch.xls");

// Insert below
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
```

Referenced: [ASP.NET Excel export encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1679656/1287352)

Comment: Great, I used the code that provided in the link , it worked perfectly, and solved the problem. I didn't know about the  Byte Order Mark (BOM) before