# Excel export haven't out properly for other languages in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I wrote following code to export excel in asp.net mvc. I encode to UTF8 so I can get English and special character what I expected. But for other languages(Chinese, etc..) I can't get proper text. Please help to solve this.

```
        str.Append("<tr>");
        str.Append("<td>Incident reports</td>");
        str.Append("<td></td>");
        str.Append("</tr>");

        //

        str.Append("</table>");

        try
        {
            return File(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToString()), "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return Json(e.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: Can you try using default encoding.(system.text.encoding.default)

Comment: Thanks Deepak, I already tried system.text.encoding.default. That one also can't solve.

Comment: You may also try as mentioned here , he has used Unicode encoding and used Response object to create and download excel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679656/asp-net-excel-export-encoding-problem

Comment: Thanks deepak, Sorry I am using MVC. So how can I make it in MVC. That example for asp.net right?

Comment: Yes it is for asp.net. In the above solution he used unicode encoding.You may try it.