# Facing issue with exporting CSV using filehelper.dll

Tags: asp.net, excel, csv, export-to-csv, filehelpers

I am exporting CSV from my asp.net web application using filehelper dll.
My code is as follows

```
 this.Response.Clear();
            this.Response.ClearContent();
            this.Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; 
 filename=" + "Unicode_CSV_Demo.csv");

            DemoCSVcls DemoCSVcls = new DemoCSVcls();
            List<DemoCSVcls> CSVTextList = new List<DemoCSVcls>();
            DemoCSVcls.Text1 = "‘tipping off’";
            DemoCSVcls.Text2 = "ʼ";
            CSVTextList.Add(DemoCSVcls);

            var engine = new FileHelperEngine<DemoCSVcls>(Encoding.UTF8);
            string finalString = engine.WriteString(CSVTextList);
            Response.BufferOutput = true;
            Response.Write(finalString);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

In above code I am passing text "‘tipping off’" but when my csv opens in default csv viewer Excel2016 then it appear like follow â€˜tipping offâ€™

but same file I am opening in notepad++ or in notepad then it appears as it is like "‘tipping off’". even its encoding is showing in Notepad++ is "UTF-8"

[image]

â€™ these text render for some specific characters only in excel.

How can I stop rendering â€™ this chracters in excel? , is there any solution to avoid this?

Comment: Got solution of my problem at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679656/asp-net-excel-export-encoding-problem